# Deserialize nested Json into a list

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to deserialize the following nested json. To do this I need the data: - state, lat, lng, time - from the json into a list. On the Newtonsoft site I can't find any information that helps me. Does anyone have an idea how I can deserialize this json?

```
    [
    {
    "data":[
        {
        "state":"STOP",
        "lat":51.99225976,
        "lng":6.97070897,
        "accuracy":55,
        "fixTime":10,
        "source":"wifi",
        "geozones":{
        },
        "address":"xyz",
        "type":"location",
        "id":1121304719,
        "time":"2022-02-18T15:15:00+0000",
        "insertTime":"2022-02-18T15:46:55+0000",
        "seqNbr":1
    },
        {
        "state":"START",
        "lat":51.99225976,
        "lng":6.97070897,
        "accuracy":55,
        "fixTime":10,
        "source":"wifi",
        "geozones":{
        },
        "address":"xyz",
        "type":"location",
        "id":1121206955,
        "time":"2022-02-18T14:50:00+0000",
        "insertTime":"2022-02-18T14:50:16+0000",
        "seqNbr":0
    },
        {
        "state":"STOP",
        "lat":51.99225976,
        "lng":6.97070897,
        "accuracy":55,
        "fixTime":10,
        "source":"wifi",
        "geozones":{
        },
        "address":"xyz",
        "type":"location",
        "id":1121167953,
        "time":"2022-02-18T14:03:00+0000",
        "insertTime":"2022-02-18T14:34:54+0000",
        "seqNbr":15
    },
        ...
],
"truncated":false,
"skipped":false,
"serial":"H3HU7Y",
"name":"SNT3.5 H3HU7Y",
"type":"seri"
}
]
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is not working for you?

Comment: Use https://app.quicktype.io/ or https://json2csharp.com/ to convert your json to classes and then deserialize to list of the root class.

Comment: These pages are really very helpful, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach is to use `JArray` and iterate through the values in the DOM, extracting them as needed:

```
var parsed = JArray.Parse(json);
foreach (var item in parsed[0]["data"])
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item["lat"]} {item["lng"]} {item["fixTime"]}");
}
```

---

However, a more robust method is to deserialize into classes.  I just pasted your json into https://json2csharp.com.  It even suggests how to deserialize your json (although, since the json represents an array I had to update to deserialize to `List<Root>`). This is the result (comments are mine):

```
// use this to deserialize
List<Root> myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Root>>(myJsonResponse);

// classes
// you'll need to define what goes here
public class Geozones
{
}

public class Datum
{
    public string state { get; set; }
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lng { get; set; }
    public int accuracy { get; set; }
    public int fixTime { get; set; }
    public string source { get; set; }
    public Geozones geozones { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public DateTime insertTime { get; set; }
    public int seqNbr { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
    public bool truncated { get; set; }
    public bool skipped { get; set; }
    public string serial { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}
```

Then to get the values:

```
foreach (var item in myDeserializedClass)
{
    foreach (var data in item.data)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine($"{data.lat} {data.lng} {data.fixTime}");
    }
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could mix the two approaches and use `ToObject<T>()`:

```
List<Datum> items = JArray.Parse(json)[0]["data"].ToObject<List<Datum>>();
```